# Shell Script get text between 2 special characters

Tags: string, shell, grep, substring

I have read a few things out there but can't seem to work out this particular problem. I am writing a shell script. I am reading a file to a variable using

```
LOCAL_CONFIG=`cat local-config.php`
```

Which has lines like this

```
define( 'DB_USER', 'abcxyz' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'qwerty' );
```

How can I get the abcxyz and the qwerty parts of this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to avoid using old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses like this: `LOCAL_CONFIG=$(cat local-config.php)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grep along with `-P` parameter to enable  perl-regexp mode.

```
$ grep -oP "\bdefine\( *'[^']*' *,  *'\K[^']*(?=' *\);)" file
abcxyz
qwerty
```

`\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final.

Comment: use `\s*` instead of space* if necessary.

Comment: That's great thanks! Also, if I wanted to get one in particular, where would I put the say "DB_USER part?"

Comment: replace the first negated char class with `DB_USER` like `grep -oP "\bdefine\( *'DB_USER' *,  *'\K[^']*(?=' *\);)" fILE`

Comment: Champion! I'll have to learn how this all works one day, thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Using awk

```
$ awk -F"'" '/^define\(/ {print $4}' local-config.php
abcxyz
qwerty
```

Explanation:

- `-F"'"`

  This defines the field separator as the single quote.
- `/^define\(/`

  This selects the lines that start with `define(`
- `print $4`

  For those selected lines, this prints the fourth field.

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -rn "/^define\(/ {s/([^']*'){3}//; s/'.*//; p;}" local-config.php
abcxyz
qwerty
```

- `-rn`

  This turns on extended regex syntax and turns off automatic printing.
- `/^define\(/`

  This selects the lines that start with `define(`
- {

  This starts a group.  Commands in this group are executed only for the selected lines.
- `s/([^']*'){3}//`

  This removes all text up through and including the third quote.
- `s/'.*//`

  This removes all text after the next remaining quote.
- `p`

  This prints the line.
- `}`

  This ends the group.

Answer (score 0):

"cut" command will do in a more simpler way...

**Command:**

```
cat local-config.php | cut -d "'" -f4
```

**output:**

```
abcxyz
qwerty
```

**Explanation:**

Using cut with ' as delimiter we need to take the fourth part(f4) in the lines.